# Oracle bi report column displaying '????????????' when downlading as PDF

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-bi

I am using Oracle Business Intelligence. I have a report that has a table created from a SQL query. The problem is when I download that report as PDF, one column shows

> ???????????

instead of the data in it. However, saving it as Excel, PowerPoint file or other formats is working fine and all data is displayed. What could be a problem?

Comment: Have you checked whether the data is simply too long to be rendered in PDF?

Comment: Chris, data is not too long, the column has only 2 words, tried to display only that column and assigned to it the highest width, but it didn't help.

Comment: When you say Oracle Business Intelligence, do you mean BI Publisher or some other tool?

Comment: What are the two words that you are trying to render? Is it possible they contain special characters that are not available in the fonts used in your PDF?

Comment: Christian Palmer, they are in Russian, that is  'Международная организация', I tried to open with three different PDF readers, in two different laptops, but no success. My PDF reader opens other PDF files in Russian with no problem.

Comment: Christian Palmer, I am using Oracle Business Intelligence EE 12.2.1.2.0.

Comment: Are ANY Cyrillic characters rendered correctly? If not then the encoding for the PDF creation for your language is the issue

Comment: Chris, unfortunately, no, all characters are rendered incorrectly and have '?' instead of the character